# Use of comma with "In order"

Tags: commas

Is the comma used correctly in these two sentences?

In order to sign and return the documents to us with EchoSign, the two initial boxes marked in red will require your initials.

In any case, there are two initial boxes marked in red which will require initials, in order to sign and return the documents to us with EchoSign.

Answer (score 2):

The reason both sentences seem somehow off is not so much a matter of punctuation as it is a problem of dangling modifiers. “The two initial boxes marked in red” do not need or wish to “sign and return the documents”; *you,* the presumed reader, need or wish to do that.

Comment: I agree. Using passive voice, which always conceals the identity of the lead actor in a sentence, leaves situations in which things are just presumed "to happen" without the use of decisions or effort.

Comment: i agree too, but with the added caveat that "in order" can almost always be omitted, which helps a writer to see more clearly the other problems with a sentence, and to recast it more clearly: "Before you sign and retun the documents, you must initial the two boxes marked in red."

Answer (score 1):

I would not place a comma in these sentences.

1. In order to sign and return the documents to us with EchoSign the two initial boxes marked in red will require your initials.
2. In any case, there are two initial boxes marked in red which will require initials in order to sign and return the documents to us with EchoSign.

There was a similar question asked on [this forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1621829) that supports this answer and provides some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sign the documents with EchoSign, and initial two boxes that are marked red before sending them back to us.